# How to see C++ template parameters while debugging with Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I found out that compile-time values are not that easy to see while debugging with Visual Studio.

Suppose that my program just **stopped at some breakpoint** in **some instantiated function template**.

There are expressions I want to examine

1. Template parameters (both type and non-type) associated with current instantiation of template
2. `constexpr` variables (which can be dependent of template parameters)
3. locally declared types with `using` (which also can be dependent of)

'Watch' and 'Immediate' windows don't seem to support those.

How can I examine those expressions **without modifying the code?**

Comment: As I remember, if you watch the value of a variable, you will see the type (with the template parameters) of a value.

Comment: @S.M. Yes I know but it helps only in some cases.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have an answer for points 2) and 3),
but the value of the template parameters shows up in the **Call Stack** in VS 2019.

[image: Screenshot showing example code breakpointed in a templated function, and the callstack shows the value of type and value template parameters.]